# Excel posted to queue successfully even if the validation fails

Tags: java, regex, excel

*Excel should not be posted to queue if validation fails. I have condition like if leadDays is negative or alphanumeric or blank, it should not be uploaded. If i'm passing negative or alphanumeric then it's not uploading but my concern is if leadDays is blank then its uploading successfully which it shouldn't.

```
if( leadDays.isEmpty() ||
                        leadDays.matches("[\\s]+") ||
                        !leadDays.matches("[0-9]+") ||
                        Double.parseDouble(leadDays) <0)
                    {
                        booleanLeadDays=true;
                        leadDaysBuff.append(count+", ");
                    }
if(booleanLeadDays){
            String[] argss= new String[1];
            argss[0] = leadDaysBuff.toString();
            errors.reject(FIELD29, argss, "");
        }
```

Comment: `leadDays.trim().isEmpty()` checks if only blank spaces are inside. if yes, it passes. if you want to change it, add a `!` before leadDays

Comment: i tried with that too but its not working

Comment: `String leadDays = "";
  if (leadDays.trim().isEmpty() || !leadDays.matches("[0-9]+")
    || Double.parseDouble(leadDays) < 0) {
   System.out.println(true);
  }else{   
   System.out.println(false);
  }`  this only prints false, if you enter a positive number. is that what you want?

Comment: When i created one small class and did the same its working fine for me but its not working with excel when leadDays=""; For you code, if leaddays is some positive no, it will print false..

Comment: when exactly should the excel be posted to the queue? then we need more code

Comment: Would require more code to debug the issue.

Comment: CSV file should be posted to queue if and only if leadDays value is positive integer.

Comment: i suppose you get the value as a string. to check if its only numerics you can use the simple regex `\\d+`